# SAS Find Top Combinations in Dataset

Tags: sas

Hell everyone --

I have some sales data which looks like this:

```
data have;
  input order_id item $;
cards;
1 A
1 B
2 A
2 C
3 B
4 A
4 B
;
run;
```

What I'm trying to find out is what are the most popular combinations of items ordered. For example in the above case, there were 2 orders that contained items A&B, 1 order of A&C, and 1 order of B. What would be the best way to output the different combinations along with the numbers of orders placed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is no permutation issue, you could try this:

```
proc sort data=have;
by order_id item;
run;

data temp;
  set have;
  by order_id;
  retain comb;
  length comb $4;
  comb=cats(comb,item);
  if last.order_id then do;
     output;
     call missing(comb);
  end;
run;

proc freq data=temp;
   table comb/norow nopercent nocol nocum;
run;
```

Comment: Actually permutation is an issue -- how would you suggest to address that?

Comment: do not do sort procedure, all the same for others.

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible approaches to this problem, and I would not presume to say which is the best. Here's a fairly simple method you could use:

1. Transpose your data so that you only have 1 row for each order, with an indicator variable for each product.
2. Feed the transposed dataset into `proc corr` to produce a correlation matrix for the indicator variables, and look for the strongest correlations.